# How to delete object on heap without causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stack, c++14, heap-memory

Hi (i am a C++ student trying to learn plz don't roast me ty in advanced),

I created `temArr` as on object on the heap.  My program compiles with no problems when i run it without deleting `temArr` which is on the heap but there is memory leaks on temArr when i run it through valgrind.  But when i run it with `delete temArr;` `temArr = nullptr;`.  I get a segmentation fault.

I have tried to make this on the stack :
`NodeList* n1(0); n1 = temArr; return n1->getNode(Index);` < this works but when do `delete temArr;` `temArr = nullptr;` it returns random variables which is not correct.

Is there a way i can values on the heap put it into the stack delete the heap then return the object that is on the stack?  Or i am i deleting my heap wrong thus it give segmentation faults?

Code :

```
Node *PathSolver::findShortDis(NodeList *openList, Node *nodeG, NodeList *closeList) {

    int Index =0;
    
    NodeList* temArr = new NodeList();
    
    for (int x = 0; x < openList->getLength(); x++) {
        if (closeListCheck(openList->getNode(x), closeList)) {
            temArr->addElement(openList->getNode(x));
        }
    }
    //assign tem to the very first node of temA
    int tem = temArr->getNode(0)->getEstimatedDist2Goal(nodeG);

    //compare
    for (int x = 0; x < temArr->getLength(); x++) {
        if (temArr->getNode(x)->getEstimatedDist2Goal(nodeG) <= tem) {
            tem = temArr->getNode(x)->getEstimatedDist2Goal(nodeG);
            Index = x;
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x <  temArr->getLength(); x++) {
        if (openList->getNode(x)->getCol() == temArr->getNode(Index)->getCol()
        && openList->getNode(x)->getRow() == temArr->getNode(Index)->getRow()){
            Index = x;
        }
    }

    // NodeList* n1(0);
    // n1 = temArr;
    // return n1->getNode(Index);

    // delete temArr;
    // temArr = nullptr;

    return temArr->getNode(Index);

}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: With `n1` being just a pointer to the same position in heap memory, naturally you can't access it after deleting that memory. If you want to transfer something to the stack, you need to copy the actual object instead of a pointer to it. For example `const auto result = temArr->getNode(Index);` before deleting and returning `result`.

Comment: If you are working with production code and not just doing this to learn about `new`/`delete`, please consider using `std::unique_ptr`, which follows the C++ RAII guideline (meaning that the destructor of the `unique_ptr` will automatically call `delete` for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncomment your `delete temArr` line, your `return` statement is trying to access `temArr` variable, after it has been delated. That's undefined behavior, and anything can happen, from getting a random value to segfaults.

Your `temArr` doesn't need to be dynamically allocated, just create it on the stack, there's a question what happens to the `Node*` pointer that you're returning after your `NodeList` has been deleted, but we can not say without seeing the rest of the code.

You will have to change all your `->` operators to `.` when calling the member functions.

```cpp
NodeList temArr{}; // Create NodeList on the stack
.
.
.
return temArr.getNode(index);
```

You could also store the value you want to return on the side, delete object and then return.

```cpp
Node* returnValue = temArr->getNode(Index);
delete temArr;
return returnValue;
```

Or use a smart pointer, that will dynamically allocate the object, but delete it when it leaves the scope.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<NodeList> temArr = std::make_unique<NodeList>();
.
.
.
return temArr->getNode(index);
```

Creating the `temArr` on the stack (1st code) is the easiest/best solution, but **make sure** that the value returned by the `getNode` method is valid **after** the `NodeList` has been deleted, in all 3 cases.

Comment: "Your temArr doesn't need to be dynamically allocated" while this might be true here, it is an assumption on your side and might not be true for future readers of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

the reason of the segfault is that you are trying to access memory that was already deleted, in other words at the line: `return temArr->getNode(Index)` you are reading from a dangling pointer.
There are a few ways to fix the problem, I’m going to suggest you the simplest.

You could allocate `temArr` directly on the stack (that is the simplest way, but if `NodeList` is too big is not great).
Using this method the destructor of the `NodeList` object will be called at the end of the function and the resources will be freed correctly.